# How to run a method on a certain day and time without opening activity?

Tags: android

I have a method that i would like to run every few days.

Lets say on ever saturday morning or sunday morning. How would i go about creating a method that will run when its a certain time or certain day?

Even if the user doesnt open the app up on the day that the method is scheduled to run, how would i go about getting the method to run automatically at a certain time?

I just want to download some strings from a website, and some images, and put them in cache.

Maybe it could be a background service that runs every sunday morning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes nearly, you would set an alarm via the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), with a pending intent whose custom action you listen to in a broadcast receiver, and start your service from there in a new thread (the new thread  <= since you're doing heavy stuff like retrieving data from the network, hence you need to spare the main thread).

Comment: Could you provide some direction on what you are suggesting? Tutorials, example code? =)

Comment: Yep, not tested but that should give you most of it : http://www.dotkam.com/2011/01/10/android-prefer-alarms-and-intent-receivers-to-services/